# How to design the multiple choices element in xml schema?

Tags: xml, xsd

For example, I want to create an element `Title` containing 3 choices: `Mr.`, `Mrs.`, `Miss`, so that users can only choose one of them. How can I do that?
Is this something like:

```
<xs:complexType name="Title">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
        Mr.
        </xs:choice>
        <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
        Mrs.
        </xs:choice>
        <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
        Miss
        </xs:choice>
   </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: I am not aware that there is a specified way to do it in XML. To my knowledge, XML only represents data and not forms. Those would be found in XHTML / HTML code. All I can say is that you could use XSLT with this XML-schema to produce a valid XHTML / HTML dropdown control, yes.

Comment: oh, So all I have to do is just making it simple like:
            <xs:element name="Title" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="3" minOccurs="0"/>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the xs:enumeration element. For example this schema restricts to documents with a single element 'Title' with 'Mr' or 'Ms' in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="XMLSchema1" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Title" type="Title"/>
  <xs:simpleType name="Title">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="Mr"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="Ms"/>
    </xs:restriction>  
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is this necessary to write mstns in type="mstns:Title"?

Comment: No - I've edited the schema so that it doesn't include a namespace.